# Show that for any point $z \in Z\subset \mathbb{C}$, $z$ can only be one of: interior, exterior, or a boundary point of $Z$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Show that for any point $z \in Z$, where $Z\subset \mathbb{C}$, the point $z$ can only be one of type of point: interior, exterior, or a boundary point of $Z$.

---

In a previous exercise, I have shown that boundary points are never interior or exterior points, so it remains to show that an interior point is never an exterior point, and if a point is not an exterior and not an exterior, then it must be a boundary point.

My question is, can these facts be proven directly? It feels like I am overlooking something subtle by proving them by contradiction, as they feel like it almost follows immediately.

For instance, I claim that an interior point is never an exterior point.

Proof: Suppose not Suppose an interior point can be an exterior point. So given an interior point $z\in Z$, there is a neighbourhood of $z$ containing only points of $Z$. Now, since $z$ is also an exterior point, there is a neighbourhood of $z$ containing no points of $Z$. This is a contradiction. QED.

Can I prove the other statements in a similar manner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point $z \in Z$, one of these three must happen:

1) There is a neighborhood $U$ of $z$ such that $U \subseteq Z$. (interior point)

2) There is a neighborhood $V$ of $z$ such that $V \cap Z = \phi$. (exterior point)

3) None of the above i.e. for every neighbourhood $W$ of $z$, $W$ intersects $Z$ (the opposite of $W \cap Z = \phi$) but also is not entirely contained in $Z$, so also intersect $Z^c$ (boundary point)

Since one of these three must happen, every point is either interior, exterior or boundary with respect to a set.